# Pause a SpriteKit scene from SwiftUI using SpriteView(isPaused:), without reinitializing it every time?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, sprite-kit, spriteview

I am trying to use the `isPaused:` argument in the [SpriteView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/spriteview) initializer to pause the `SKScene` when a state property changes in SwiftUI.

But when I use the state variable as an argument to `isPaused:` in the initializer like:

```swift
SpriteView(scene: scene, isPaused: showingLevelChooser)
```

instead of only:

```swift
SpriteView(scene: scene)
```

the scene is recreated every time the variable changes, which is not what I want. I only want to pause the game.

I am confused how is the `isPaused:` argument supposed to work. There isn't much information in the [SpriteView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/spriteview).

As far as I understand this happens because SwiftUI recreates the views that are dependent on the state. But if this is the case, **how can you pause the SpriteKit scene from SwiftUI, without reinitializing it every time?**

I created a sample Xcode 13 project here: https://github.com/clns/SpriteView-isPaused

The `SKScene` is displaying the "*Time Elapsed*" on the screen, in seconds. Every time the SwiftUI sheet is presented and the state variable `showingLevelChooser` changes, the timer starts from 0 (zero), because the scene is reinitialized.

[image: Visual_Demonstration]

All relevant code is in [ContentView.swift](https://github.com/clns/SpriteView-isPaused/blob/main/SpriteView-isPaused/ContentView.swift).

```swift
class GameScene: SKScene {
    private let label = SKLabelNode(text: "Time Elapsed:\n0")
    private var lastUpdateTime : TimeInterval = 0
    
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        addChild(label)
    }
    
    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        if (self.lastUpdateTime == 0) {
            self.lastUpdateTime = currentTime
        }
        
        let seconds = Int(currentTime - lastUpdateTime)
        label.text = "Time Elapsed:\n\(seconds)"
        label.numberOfLines = 2
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingLevelChooser = false
    
    var scene: SKScene {
        let scene = GameScene()
        scene.size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 400)
        scene.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        scene.scaleMode = .fill
        return scene
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            SpriteView(scene: scene, isPaused: showingLevelChooser)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack {
                Button("Level Chooser") {
                    showingLevelChooser.toggle()
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingLevelChooser) {
            VStack {
                Button("Cancel") {
                    showingLevelChooser.toggle()
                }
                Text("Level Chooser")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues to take care of here. The first is that you want to have a reference to your `SKScene` that will stick around. Making it a computed property of the `View` will not work (as you're experiencing) because the `View` is transitive and every time it gets reloaded, you'll get a new `SKScene`.

There are multiple acceptable solutions to this, but I chose to encapsulate the `SKScene` in an `ObservableObject` that you can hold a reference to via `StateObject`. You could even experiment with making the `SKScene` an `ObservableObject` itself (not shown here).

Secondly, your logic for determine/showing the "pause" on screen was going to be a little tough to accurately see, because it always just displayed the elapsed time -- there was no logic involved to not count the time during the pause. I replaced it with a simple counter that shows the number of updates. That way, you can clearly tell that the scene has indeed been paused (and doesn't update).

```
class SceneStore : ObservableObject {
    var scene = GameScene()
    
    init() {
        scene.size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 400)
        scene.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        scene.scaleMode = .fill
    }
}

class GameScene: SKScene {
    private let label = SKLabelNode(text: "Updates: 0")
    private var updates = 0
    
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        addChild(label)
    }
    
    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        updates += 1
        label.text = "Updates: \(updates)"
        label.numberOfLines = 2
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingLevelChooser = false
    @StateObject private var sceneStore = SceneStore()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            SpriteView(scene: sceneStore.scene, isPaused: showingLevelChooser)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack {
                Button("Level Chooser") {
                    showingLevelChooser.toggle()
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingLevelChooser) {
            VStack {
                Button("Cancel") {
                    showingLevelChooser.toggle()
                }
                Text("Level Chooser")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed using `ObservableObject` - `StateObject` works as intended. Thanks @jnpdx. One related question, if I need to **track the paused state inside the SKScene**, I would call a method on the scene, maybe in the [onChange(of:perform:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onchange%28of:perform:%29) modifier? Something like `.sheet(...){...}.onChange(of: showingLevelChooser) { scene.isPaused($0) }`?

Comment: Seems like a reasonable approach -- have you tested it out?